# Plotting coordinates from *.csv file on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, csv

I want to highlight a mobile trace on Google Maps and GIS data from my network must also be visible.

I am able to plot hard coded coordinates on Google Maps but not from a *.csv file.

Note: *.csv file contains Lat & Long values to highlight traced route

I am able to highlight the route now but if I enter too many coordinates then the page responses very slowly.

Can anyone let me know the limits?

I post my code below, so you can see if I am going in wrong direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MySiteMap</title>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDuSN0u2fpgle4eYZ1kxPHmTA8maKJynYE&sensor=false">
</script>
<script src="label.js"></script>  
<script>
    var a_Lat=new Array();
    var a_Long=new Array();
    var myLatLong = new Array();
    var myOtherSite = new Array();
    var myTataSite = new Array();
    var map;  
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(18.980599,75.766536);  
    function initialize() {  
        ///sets lat_long values for polyline.
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var excel_file_r = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Priyanka\\EGIS\\somefile.xls");
        var excel_file_s = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Priyanka\\EGIS\\sitefile.xls");
        var excel_sheet_r = excel_file_r.Worksheets("sheet1");
        var excel_sheet_s = excel_file_s.Worksheets("sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet_r.Cells(1,2).Value;
        alert("kklk");
        for (var i=2; i<10000; i++) {
            if (excel_sheet_r.Cells(i,1).Value==undefined || excel_sheet_r.Cells(i,2).Value==undefined) {
               break;
            }
            a_Lat[i-2]=excel_sheet_r.Cells(i,1).Value;
            a_Long[i-2]=excel_sheet_r.Cells(i,2).Value;
            myLatLong[i-2]=new google.maps.LatLng(a_Lat[i-2],a_Long[i-2]);
        }
        ///sets latlong for Tata Sites
        var counter_a = 0;
        for (var i=2; i<10000; i++) {
            if (excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,1).Value==undefined || excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,2).Value==undefined) {
            break;
            } else {
            myTataSite[i-2]=new google.maps.LatLng(excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,1).Value,excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,2).Value);
            counter_a = counter_a + 1;
            }   
        }
        alert(counter_a);
        var counter1_a = 0; 
        ///sets latlong for ICR Sites
        for (var i=2; i<10000; i++) {   
            if (excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,3).Value==undefined || excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,4).Value==undefined) {
                break;
            } else {
                myOtherSite[i-2]=new google.maps.LatLng(excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,3).Value,excel_sheet_s.Cells(i,4).Value);
                counter1_a = counter1_a + 1;
            }
        }
        alert(counter1_a);
        ///Release Excel object.
        excel.Quit(); 
        excel = null; 
        alert("BYE");   
        ///sets map properties
        var mapProp = {
            center:myLatLong[1],
            zoom:4,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        ///Map object is defined
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        //------------------First KML file.......
        var ctaLayer3 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
            url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/turbhegiskmlfiles/gis/cluster_boundry.kml'  
            });
        //------------------second KML file......
        var ctaLayer4 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
            url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/turbhegiskmlfiles/gis/WRL_Kolhpaur.kml'  
            });
        var myTrip = new Array();
        ///-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------///
        ///-----------------------------------DEFINE POLYLINE-----------------------------------------------------///
        ///-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------///
        myTrip = myLatLong;
        var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
            path:myTrip,
            strokeColor:"#FF00FF",
            strokeOpacity:0.8,
            strokeWeight:5
        });
        ///Place marker on clicked location 
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
            addruler(event.latLng);
        });
        alert("set")   
        var mySiteTata = new Array();
        var markerTata = new Array();
        var mySiteOther = new Array();
        var markerOther = new Array();
        var infowindow1;
        ///sets TATA sites
        for (var i=0;i<500;i++) {
            markerTata[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myTataSite[i],
                icon:'tata.png'
                });
            mySiteTata[i] = new google.maps.Circle({
                center:myTataSite[i],
                radius:2000,
                strokeColor:"#0099FF",
                strokeOpacity:0.8,
                strokeWeight:2,
                fillColor:"#99FFFF",
                fillOpacity:0.1
            });
            infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:"Tata Site"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(markerTata[i], 'mouseover', function() {
                infowindow1.open(map,markerTata[i])
            });   
            mySiteTata[i].setMap(map);
            markerTata[i].setMap(map);              
        }
       ///sets ICR sites
       for (var i=0;i<counter1_a;i++) {
            markerOther[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myOtherSite[i],
                icon:'home.png'
            });
            mySiteOther[i] = new google.maps.Circle({
                center:myOtherSite[i],
                radius:2000,
                strokeColor:"#CC00CC",
                strokeOpacity:0.8,
                strokeWeight:2,
                fillColor:"#CCCCFF",
                fillOpacity:0.1
            });         
            mySiteOther[i].setMap(map);
            markerOther[i].setMap(map);     
        }           
        ctaLayer3.setMap(map);
        ctaLayer4.setMap(map);
        flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
    function placeMarker(location) {
        var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
                map: map
            });
        var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
            });
            infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
        }
    /*
    javascript ruler for google maps V3
    by Giulio Pons. http://www.barattalo.it
    this function uses the label class from Marc Ridley Blog
     */
    function addruler(location) {
        var ruler1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
        var ruler2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location ,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
       });
       var ruler1label = new Label({ map: map });
       var ruler2label = new Label({ map: map });
       ruler1label.bindTo('position', ruler1, 'position');
       ruler2label.bindTo('position', ruler2, 'position');
       var rulerpoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
           path: [ruler1.position, ruler2.position] ,
           strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
           strokeOpacity: .7,
           strokeWeight: 4
       });
       rulerpoly.setMap(map);
       ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
       ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
       google.maps.event.addListener(ruler1, 'drag', function() {
           rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
           ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
           ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
       });
       google.maps.event.addListener(ruler2, 'drag', function() {
           rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
           ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
           ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
       });
    }  
    function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
        var R = 6371; // km (change this constant to get miles)
        var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
        var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180; 
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var d = R * c;
        if (d>1) return Math.round(d)+"km";
        else if (d<=1) return Math.round(d*1000)+"m";
        return d;
    }
    function all_clear(){
        alert("Here")
        map.setMap(null);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-family:arial;color:magenta;font-size:20px;"> This is My web Page </p><br><br>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:580px;"></div> <br><br><br><br>
    <p>Data in Excel is : **3652 https://sites.google.com/site/turbhegiskmlfiles/gis/shirur_to_ahmednagar.kml **</p>
    <p id = "demo"> Data is as follows: </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a background in PHP a possible solution might be the following:

To keep things absolutely simple, use Googles' CSV parser library for PHP

[Link to CSV parser for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/)

Then make sure you have the latitude and longitude values in your CSV. Once you have done that, parse the CSV and make a stdClass php object from each rows' coordinates. Something like this:

```
<?php
  $coordinates = array();
  for($i=0;$i<count($rows_number_of_csv);$i++){
  $coordinates = new stdClass();
  $coordinates->latitude = $latitude_value_from_row;
  $coordinates->longitude = $longitude_value_from_row;  
  array_push($points, $coordinates);
  unset($coordinates);
  }

  //Now that you have the array of points, echo it using PHP's json_encode function

  echo json_encode($points);
?>
```

Now this PHP file give you the set of points in a nice JSON format, that you can easily process on the client side with JS and Google Maps API v3.

Let me know if you need any more info on this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the maps engine lite on the site:
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/?gmp=msp&pli=1
upload the csv file or convert to a xlsx format and upload.
If you have it as a excel file there may be formating problems if it was not a cleansed csv where you have a x & y columnar lat long comma delimited text file formatting

Answer (score -1):

Google has a step by step tutorial that is close to what you want
https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/csvtokml

If you have Arcgis just convert the csv to a shapefile then use http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html to do it for you.